# Getting an swift class var without Optional("value")

Tags: swift2

I'm creating a utility to add archival events to a calendar.

example run

```
./create-events-from-dvd-contents.swift --path /Volumes/ARCHIVE/DVD\ 1255/2451-01_LLA_Assets\ Folder\ Nov\ 2015/
Optional("DVD 1255")
```

The class is

```
class Event {
    var location: String? ;
    var start: String? ;
    var notes: String? ;
}
```

The code to print the dvd location is

```
let event = Event() ;
let pathArray = path.characters.split {$0 == "/"}.map { String($0) } ;
event.location = pathArray[2] ; 
print(event.location) ;
```

What is the simplest way to get 'DVD 1255' output instead of 'Optional("DVD 1255")'?

Comment: I guess the real question here is what do you want to print when event.location is nil. To unwrap the optional if you're sure it's never nil you probably know that `print(event.location!)` would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must unwrap the value first into its own (non optional) variable.

```
let event = Event() ;
let pathArray = path.characters.split {$0 == "/"}.map { String($0) } ;
event.location = pathArray[2];

if let location = event.location { 
    print(location);
}
```

or you could put an ! after event.location if you wanted.

```
let event = Event() ;
let pathArray = path.characters.split {$0 == "/"}.map { String($0) } ;
event.location = pathArray[2] ; 
print(event.location!) ;
```

Comment: also, I recommend deleting the ```;```s from your code

Comment: I code in many other languages that require a ; . That's why I use semi-colons in swift.

Comment: I'm now deleting ; from any swift code I write. Thanks @Casey.

Answer (score 0):

The nil-coalescing operator is a clean way to do this:

```
var x: String? = "foo"
print(x) // Optional('foo')

x = nil
var y: String = x ?? "bar" // note y is not an optional

print(y) // Bar
print(x ?? "Not optional") // Not optional
```

Also, I noticed you are using semi-colons, which are unnecessary in Swift. I mention this, not as an opinion, but because it is a good practice of Swift to not use semi-colons unless necessary (multiple statements on one line or something)